# Setting Specific Session Variable (user specific image folder)

Tags: joomla-3.x, session, images, jsession

I'm trying to integrate http://responsivefilemanager.com/ into joomla to replace the normal image manager so I can have per user image folder option.
I managed to integrate it reasonably well into TinyMCE, but now have to set

```
$_SESSION["RF"]["subfolder"] ="subfolder/$user/"
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to set this properly.

This is for joomla 3x

If someone has another solution to set a user specific image folder, I'm all ears :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure as to why this specific session needs to be set, but I'll go alone with it.

To set a session value, you can use the following:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('subfolder', 'value');
```

To in your case, if you want to get the logged in user's name and it it for the path, you can do the following:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('subfolder', JFactory::getUser()->username);
```

#### Update with PHP native session

```
$username = JFactory::getUser()->username;
$_SESSION['RF']['subfolder'] = "subfolder/$username /";
```

Hope this helps

Comment: from documentation of responsivefilemanager:
STARTQUOTE
You can set a subfolder as root.
So you can have a root folder for each user.

The way to implement this is set the session variable $_SESSION["RF"]["subfolder"] ="subfolder/name/"
ENDQUOTE

With this way you suggest, will this also set those RF letters, I saw the documentation of joomla, but this does not go along with setting a certain session right(I think that is what the RF is for)? This would just add it to the joomla session, which won't be seen by responisvefilemanager. Thanks for taking the time to help out though :)

Comment: @Naithan - In which case, simply use PHP's native session as you did in your question.

Comment: Am I still able to make use of the JFactory::getUser()->username); then though? And where could I set this on login?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use JCE Editor. This extension has this option each user can see only his directory:

https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/downloads/editor/joomla-3

Here you can see this configuration:

https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/tutorials/editor/item/setting-the-file-directory-path